# hts non-conformable arrays forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, hts

Hi everyone I am trying to calculate the accuracy statistics for Hierarchical Time Series, using the hts package, but I get an error that says "Error in x - fcasts : non-conformable arrays".

```
library(hts)
abc <- matrix(sample(1:100, 32*140, replace=TRUE), ncol=32)
colnames(abc) <- c(
  paste0("A0",1:5), 
  paste0("B0",1:9),"B10",
  paste0("C0",1:8),
  paste0("D0",1:5),
  paste0("E0",1:4)
)
abc <- ts(abc, start=2019, frequency=365.25/7)
x <- hts(abc, characters = c(1,2))

data <- window(x, start = 2019.000, end = 2021.166)
test <- window(x, start = 2021.185)
fcasts <- forecast(data, h = 20, method = "bu")
accuracy(fcasts, test)
accuracy(fcasts test, levels = 1)
```

Then the error message is:

```
> data <- window(x, start = 2019.000, end = 2021.166)
> test <- window(x, start = 2021.185)
> fcasts <- forecast(data, h = 20, method = "bu")
There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> accuracy(fcasts, test)
Error in x - fcasts : non-conformable arrays
> accuracy(fcasts, test, levels = 1)
Error in x - fcasts : non-conformable arrays
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the `hts` package, which I've now fixed in the dev version (https://github.com/earowang/hts/commit/3f444cf6d6aca23a3a7f2d482df2e33bb078dc55).

Using the CRAN version, the problem is avoided by using the same forecast horizon (`h`) as the length of the test set.

There was another bug in `accuracy()` triggered by weekly data which I've also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs because of the list object for **fcasts** and **test**.

Try this:

```
accuracy(fcasts$bts, test$bts)
accuracy(fcasts$bts, test$bts, levels = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks I basically re runned this command devtools::install_github("earowang/hts") which contained the fix